# Pass pointer to struct by reference in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Take in mind the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}A;

A *test;

void init(A* a)
{
    a->a = 3;
    a->b = 2;
    a->c = 1;
}
int main()
{
    test = malloc(sizeof(A));
    init(test);
    printf("%d\n", test->a);
    return 0;
}
```

It runs fine! Now imagine that I want to use the `malloc` function outside the `main` itself without returning a pointer to the `struct`. I would put malloc inside `init` and pass `test` adress. But this doesnt seem to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}A;

A *test;

void init(A** a)
{
    *a = malloc(sizeof(A));
    *a->a = 3;
    *a->b = 2;
    *a->c = 1;
}
int main()
{
    init(&test);
    printf("%d\n", test->a);
    return 0;
}
```

It keeps telling me that int `a`(or `b`/`c`) is not a member of the `struct A` when I use the pointer.

Comment: I bet that's not what it's telling you. What's the actual error message?

Comment: @melpomene request for member 'a' in something not a structure or union

Comment: See? It doesn't even mention `struct A`. It says the thing you're trying to use isn't a `struct` at all. (As the answers below explain, your code is getting parsed as `*(a->a)`, `a->a` is the same as `(*a).a`, and the type of `*a` is `A *`; i.e. the compiler thinks you're trying to access members of a pointer, which makes no sense.)

Comment: and just an fyi,, there is no pass-by-reference in C,, it's all pass-by-value. In this case, you're passing a pointer by value to `init` where it's dereferenced and operated on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must add parenthesis:

```
void init(A **a)
{
    *a = malloc(sizeof(A)); // bad you don't verify the return of malloc
    (*a)->a = 3;
    (*a)->b = 2;
    (*a)->c = 1;
}
```

But it's good practice to do this:

```
void init(A **a)
{
    A *ret = malloc(sizeof *ret); // we want the size that is referenced by ret
    if (ret != NULL) { // you should check the return of malloc
        ret->a = 3;
        ret->b = 2;
        ret->c = 1;
    }
    *a = ret;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is operator precedence.  The `->` operator has higher precedence than the `*` (dereference) operator, so `*a->a` is read as if it is `*(a->a)`.  Change `*a->a` to `(*a)->a`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}A;

A *test;

void init(A** a)
{
    *a = malloc(sizeof(A));
    (*a)->a = 3;
    (*a)->b = 2;
    (*a)->c = 1;
}
int main()
{
    init(&test);
    printf("%d\n", test->a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to write `(*a)->a = 3;` for reasons of precedence.

Comment: Wow didn't really think it was a question of syntax. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Even though it's not a direct answer to your question, since we're in the vicinity of initialization I'd like to point out that C11 gives you a nicer syntax to initialize structs:

```
void init(A **a)
{
    A *ret = malloc(sizeof *ret); // we want the size that is referenced by ret
    if (ret != NULL) { // you should check the return of malloc
        *ret = (A) {3, 2, 1};
        // or
        *ret = (A) { .a = 3, .b = 2, .c = 1 };
    }
    *a = ret;
}
```

Another advantage is that any uninitialized members are zeroed.

Comment: It's very interesting an user friendly doc is [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal). But I want to know if it's create a temporary variable or if it's only affect the struct.